# Trim Data Based on First Character of Column Name

Tags: r, package

I have a data set with multiple columns. Using `R` I want to keep only those column that have first character as `T` to create a subset as shown in output data below.

**Input Data**

```
T1234 T5678 T9101112 A B D E
  1     2       3    4 5 6 7
  1     2       3    4 5 6 7
  1     2       3    4 5 6 7
  1     2       3    4 5 6 7
  1     2       3    4 5 6 7
  1     2       3    4 5 6 7
  1     2       3    4 5 6 7
```

**Output Data**

```
T1234 T5678 T9101112
  1     2       3   
  1     2       3   
  1     2       3   
  1     2       3   
  1     2       3   
  1     2       3   
  1     2       3
```

Any suggestion how this can be achieved? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R using RegEx

```
df <- data.frame(T1234=rep(1,7),T5678=2,T9101112=3,A=4,B=5,D=6,E=7)

df[,grepl("^T",names(df))]
```

The regex pattern `^T` matches T at the beginning of each row name. You could refine the pattern to `^T\\d+` if you wanted to match just "T" followed by 1 or more numbers, as another example.

Also note that `^` asserts that you're at the beginning of the string. Without it you'd match "AT912340" because it contains a T.

For multiple characters (i.e. columns that start with T or M) we'd use the "or" operator `|`

```
df[,grepl("^T|M",names(df))]
```

And to match groups of characters like RDY or MTP we'd do it like this:

```
df[,grepl("^T|MTP|Check|RDY",names(df))]
```

*Note: in the comments I mistakenly used brackets like so: [T,M]. Using brackets tells RegEx to match one of the characters in the brackets, so in this case it would match "T", "M", or ",". Obviously we don't want to match a comma here, and it's syntactically incorrect to have the commas in the brackets separating each character. To match "T" or "M" the correct syntax with brackets would be [TM], however, to match words, or short strings like above, we must use* `|` *as the "or" operator.*

Comment: .@Mako212 - Thanks, it works. Can I extend this to add multiple patterns. For example: I want to keep column with `T*` and also with `M*`. I can write multiple `df[,grepl("^T.*",names(df))]` and `df[,grepl("^M.*",names(df))]` and then `cbind()` them to get one `data`

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil no need to write multiple statements unless the RegEx starts getting too messy to keep track of.

Comment: .@Mako212 - The data set I have needs to be trimmed based on these `"^[T,MTP,Check,RDY]"`, but what I see is that columns with first character as `P` and `M` are also being trimmed along with it. `grepl` should match `MTP` with first three characters for column name and then decide whether to trim or not? Similarly for `Check` and `RDY`?

Comment: .@Mako212 - Trim I used for extracting the data, the goal is similar to what I asked in the question. I want to use your solution only, but with columns matching starting letters with one of `T,MTP,Check,RDY`.

Comment: For that case I'd switch to using the pipe `|` "or" operator like this: `df[,grepl("^T|MTP|Check|RDY",names(df))]` and I think that should work.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil I should note that my use of brackets earlier wasn't correct. RegEx will match one of any character within brackets, so [MOP] would match an M, an O, or a P. My usage was in the form [M,O,P], which would have matched a comma (although it's not a legal column name in a data frame), if it was in the beginning of a row name. In short, use the pipe for "or", unless you just need to match one of several characters in a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
> require(dplyr)
> df <- data.frame(T1234=rep(1,7),T5678=2,T9101112=3,A=4,B=5,D=6,E=7)
> df
  T1234 T5678 T9101112 A B D E
1     1     2        3 4 5 6 7
2     1     2        3 4 5 6 7
3     1     2        3 4 5 6 7
4     1     2        3 4 5 6 7
5     1     2        3 4 5 6 7
6     1     2        3 4 5 6 7
7     1     2        3 4 5 6 7
> select(df,starts_with('T'))
  T1234 T5678 T9101112
1     1     2        3
2     1     2        3
3     1     2        3
4     1     2        3
5     1     2        3
6     1     2        3
7     1     2        3
>
```

Or, without `dplyr`

```
> df[,grepl('T',colnames(df))]
     T1234 T5678 T9101112
1     1     2        3
2     1     2        3
3     1     2        3
4     1     2        3
5     1     2        3
6     1     2        3
7     1     2        3
>
```

but the latter will hit the T in any position.

Comment: .@mrbcuda - Thanks. Can this be done _without_ `dplyr()`?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without using `regex` :

```
df[,substr(names(df),1,1) %in% c("T","M")]
```